# Angular: Should an HTML canvas be a Component or a Service?

Tags: angular, typescript, model-view-controller, raphael

I have a basic drawing App which implements an MVC framework in Javascript (actually ts) and I'd like to port it into Angular. I have a Model to handle the data, a View to draw shapes on the canvas and a Controller to update the model and view components. In porting to Angular it seems clear that the model should be a service. However, it seems like the controller should be a component with either: 1) the View as a subcomponent (without any actual HTML since it just takes the HTML canvas component and runs with it) or a service. What's the best/typical approach in this sort of case?

Answer (score 0):

> Should an HTML canvas be a Component or a Service?

Component. HTML / rendering to screen stuff makes sense as a component.

Answer (score 0):

You have prob heard of MVC (model view controller) or MVVC (model view view-controller)

A service essentially fulfils the model role and should do the heavy lifting.

The view renders stuff, which you don't seem to really need here apart from maybe a div tag to bind the canvas to.

The controller provides the lightweight communication between the service and the view.

Given that you don't really have a view, you are going to be much better off using an attribute directive (AKA directive). Think of a directive as a component without a view.

You could prob use a service in conjunction with the attribute directive although I have never tried this and the docs don't seem to cover it, but its prob very straightforward, using DI (dependency injection) via the constructor.

Here's the docs for an attribute directive:

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Note from the docs that a component is officially a type of directive but is rarely referred to as such in every day use.

Comment: Thanks. I have been thinking along these lines. I'm using a heavy-service for my data model as you said, and components--parent(controller) and child(view) to house the drawing. I'll just need to add an additional lightweight-service or perhaps observable to use as an event handler.